# Wireless router causing my wireless mouse to lag

Tags: wireless-networking

I've recently found the cause of my mouse lag (Logitech Desktop Wave), which usually works perfectly without any lag at all, except for when there is activity on my wireless network.

Clearly it is the wireless router interfering with the mouse. I logged into the router admin, and found it has the ability to switch the channel. There are actually 13 options.

I decided to try change, but if anything it made the lag worse.

Do I really have to try out all the channels by trial and error, or has anyone found a particular channel that works well with Desktop Wave?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Logitech finds a clean channel when it is first initialized.  Or at least, it is supposed to.  Therefore, nobody can tell you a channel to use, because what interferes for you may not interfere for anyone else.  What I can tell you is that channels overlap quite a bit.  Start with channel one, and see how bad it is.  Then try channel 6, and then 11.  Then dial it in from there as to the best channel to use.  If neither channels 1, 6, or 11 work, then return your wireless keyboard for a different brand that doesn't use so much spectrum.